# Prove that there are infinitely many natural numbers that cannot be written as the sum of $6$ natural number squares.

Tags: number-theory

I am stumped on this problem. The furthest I have got is to assume that there exists a largest number $N$ that cannot be written as the sum of $6$ squares. Ideally, I was trying to get a contradiction by constructing a larger number, dependant on $N$, that cannot be written as the sum of $6$ squares, but I have gotten nowhere with that.

Comment: What about Lagrange's theorem:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_four-square_theorem ?

Comment: I am sorry for not mentioning that the squares are squares of natural numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

even if you don't allow 0 it's not true. Legendre's theorem says you can write a number as the sum of three squares iff it isn't in the form $4^n(8k+7)$.for n write it as the sum of $m+t$ such that m is sum of three nonzero square and t is of the form $8k+3$ which must be sum of three nonzero square. the only problem occurs when $n=8k+10=12+(8(k-1)+6)$ and again each of $12$ and $8k+6$ are sum of three nonzero square.